# C++ range based loops - How do they work?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

I'll preface this question by saying I am knowledgeable on C, and I'm learning C++.

Suppose I've got an std::string object and I want to go thru all of its characters to verify it (for example, only 4 letters allowed).

I have seen `for (type var : array)` being used in some code around a week ago, but I couldn't remember how it was used. I'm wondering.. exactly how does this work, and why does it work? Logically it shouldn't.

AFAIK, arrays don't really "know" what their length is. So suppose I have this code:

```cpp
int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
for (int item : arr) {
    std::cout << item << std::endl;
}
```

How the hell does the `for loop` know when to stop? Arrays are simply put allocated memory (stack, in this case) that start from a specific address and go on. There's no "stored length" (AFAIK) for arrays. This is why it is a programmer's responsibility to store the length of the array, and do `for (int i = 0; i < [length]; i++)` but this somehow works?

Would love some explanation. Specific use case for my code:

```cpp
std::string test = "Hello World!";
for (char letter : test) {
    if (letter == 'l') {
        std::cout << "'l' exists!" << std::endl;
    } // result should be 3 prints.
}
```

Comment: Of course an arrays has a known length, how else would the compiler know how much space to allocate for it? Are you confusing arrays with arrays decayed to pointers?

Comment: arrays in C and C++ are very different, the big one being that C++ arrays know their size.

Comment: @cigien: unless you're talking about the `std::array` *class,* C++ knows as much about its arrays as C does.

Comment: @paxdiablo But in `int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3 };` the size of `arr` is part of its type. That's not the case in C, right?

Comment: @cigien I'm used to C arrays, so I'm very confused about how C++ handles this type of loop. Also, another thing that confuses me is, why is it only supported in C++11 and up?

Comment: Because that's when it was added to the language, that's all :) Spend some time reading the dupe target, it explains how the loop works.

Comment: @cigien `int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3 };` is the exact same thing in C and C++, it deduces `arr` to be of type `int[3]`

Comment: The linked answer (dupe) only explains how the variable is initialized (the variable x). It does not explain how it works behind the scenes in terms of memory. This is what interests me. 

I want to know where this supposed length is stored.

Comment: Oh, I see you're asking specifically about `range-for` with arrays. I've added a specific duplicate target for that as well.

Comment: @UnholySheep Oh, really? I haven't written C in over a decade, but I remember needing to do `sizeof` tricks to figure out the size of a C array.

Comment: @cigien You mean `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr)`? Wouldn't you do the exact same thing in C++ for a C-style array? And isn't that also what `std::end()` and `std::size()` do for arrays?

Comment: @UnholySheep For a C-style array, sure. But that's just `int*`, and there's no C-style array in the OP's code. And you can't do `begin` `end` or use `range-for` loops with C-style arrays.

Comment: @cigien Actually, great that you've pointed this out. Will the `for-range` loop work with `int* arr = new arr[5];`?

Comment: @yeho Why don't you try compiling the code yourself? Best way to find out :)

Comment: `this range-based 'for' statement requires a suitable "begin" function and none was found`

Comment: That's correct :) In C++, we call `int*` C-style arrays (and as far as I recall, those are the only kind of arrays in C), and you can't compute `begin` and `end` for them, so they can't be used in `range-for` loops.

Comment: Mhm. In C, there's `int arr[]` and `int* arr`, but functionally they're identical. If it's different in C++, according to you, how is it handled in the background? Is a C++ array an object? Moreover, is `begin` [0] and `end` [-1] (python reference)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is all covered in whatever resources you're using to learn C++. I'm happy to answer questions, but now the topic is deviating away from the question in the post, and so I have to stop the discussion. SO is not really a tutorial site, or a discussion forum, I'm afraid. Hope you understand :)